# Git Push and Commit are not publsihing

Tags: github

I have made some changes to my local file and git add. git commit, git push it several times but it hasn't been published on my site. I checked Deployment but it doesn't seem to be deployed. My site is https://github.com/shielarlamb/portfolio. I tried quite a few solutions but it seems like it is detached. [image]

Here are some of the results of what I did. I apologize if it is messy. I am not very experience on this.

My ultimate goal is to publish the changes I made. I appreciate all your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try to check the current branches by the command `git branch`
If you get no branches named `main` but `master` like this

[image: git branch]

then try this command `git push -u origin master`

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. 

Here's what I got:

PS C:\Users\aleis\Documents\Github\portfolio> git branch
  alt-history
* gh-pages
  master
PS C:\Users\aleis\Documents\Github\portfolio> git push -u origin master
Everything up-to-date
branch 'master' set up to track 'origin/master'.

Comment: So it is solved, right?

Comment: Unfortunately, not. :(

Comment: By now your repo is up to date with GitHub
so I think the point is with deployment
Are you deploying to GitHub pages?

Comment: Yes. :) I used to just be able to add, commit, and push and it update my pages. I can see the changes in the Github file but it is not showing when I got to the link.

Comment: Usually, Github pages take time to update the changes, but not that long.
You may try reloading your site using `CTRL + F5`. If that does not fix it, try reading [this page](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/setting-up-a-github-pages-site-with-jekyll/about-jekyll-build-errors-for-github-pages-sites).
Else, you may wait for a more experienced developer to help you :)

Comment: Amir, Thank you! I waited for over 2 days but I think it has something to do with my subscription. :)